# Objective C: @property gone after loading viewDidLoad again

Tags: objective-c, variables, properties

I'm new in the App Development and am working on my first real App.
I thought I understood the property variable in a header file but I don't really get whats happening here... I've got a solution but don't understand why it works.

I passed a String through from another ViewController and wrote it in my property Variable:

**ViewController.h:**

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) NSString *Gender;
```

Now my viewDidLoad (**ViewController.m**) starts:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad];

self.TestLabel.text = _Gender;  ...}
```

Everything is fine and the Label shows my String.
But when I press my Button "Reset" (still ViewController.m):

```
- (IBAction)ButtonReset:(id)sender { [self viewDidLoad] }
```

Everything works as before but my Label is empty and it acts like the String does not exist.

**Solution I came up with by trying something out:**

Adding a global variable in my ViewController.m

```
NSString *boygirl;
```

Then changing my original Code into:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad];   
boygirl = _Gender;
self.TestLabel.text = boygirl; ...}
```

...
Why does that work? Is there a more elegant way?
If Gender can't be called in my original code... why can boygirl get the Gender again?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property is declared as "weak", which means as soon as there are no other references to that same string, your property will be set to nil. It sounds like you meant "strong" there.

Also, you should not call viewDidLoad yourself, and your property names really should start lowercase. These aren't the source of your issue, but good things to learn early on I think.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So I've got this quiz going on in my ViewController. And when I answered, I save the Answer in a global variable. After that I reset my App to the beginning by calling viewDidLoad... how can I do it more elegantly?

Comment: Duh, figured it out. Don't know why I didn't come up with that.
I just wrote a new Method called 'resetApp' and pasted in everything that was inside my viewDidLoad Method. Called it once in my viewDidLoad and after that, if I want to reset my app, I simply call resetApp.

Comment: That sounds like a better solution. Good luck with the app.